# c++ error: ‘staticint’ was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++

I am new to C++,I am trying to grasp static Storage:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// Function definition
void func(void)
{
staticint i =5;// local static variable
i++;
cout <<"i is "<< i ;
cout <<" and count is "<< count << endl;
cout <<" count ref "<< &count << endl;
}

int main()
{
staticint count =10;/* Global variable */
while(count--)
{ func();}
return0;
}
```

When I compile I got:

```
b1.cc: In function ‘void func()’:
b1.cc:7:1: error: ‘staticint’ was not declared in this scope
 staticint i =5;// local static variable
 ^
b1.cc:7:11: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘i’
 staticint i =5;// local static variable
           ^
b1.cc:8:1: error: ‘i’ was not declared in this scope
 i++;
 ^
b1.cc:10:27: error: ‘count’ was not declared in this scope
 cout <<" and count is "<< count << endl;
                           ^
b1.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
b1.cc:16:1: error: ‘staticint’ was not declared in this scope
 staticint count =10;/* Global variable */
 ^
b1.cc:16:11: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘count’
 staticint count =10;/* Global variable */
           ^
b1.cc:17:7: error: ‘count’ was not declared in this scope
 while(count--)
       ^
b1.cc:19:1: error: ‘return0’ was not declared in this scope
 return0;
```

So the question is where should I define staticint to serve as local static variable?Do I need special module for the variables?

Comment: `staticint` --> `static int` and `return0` --> `return 0`. When compiler complains about a line, usually it's a good idea to look at that line for any errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's `static int`, not `staticint`.

Answer (score 1):

Just like you can't declare an int with `intcount`, you can't declare a static int with `staticint`.

No whitespace between alphanumerics/underscores makes the compiler interpret the words as a single identifier.

Also, `func` can't access `count` because it's local in `main`, not global as your comment says.

To make a variable global it needs to be declared outside *any* function, including the `main` function.